# Creating new conversation. Missing an import. getting following error: WebApiApplication does not contain a definition for FindContainer()

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm creating a chatbot and i'm trying to implement the creation of a new conversation following Microsofts example at:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-CreateNewConversation

However in the SurveyTrigger.cs they use the following command:

```
var container = WebApiApplication.FindContainer();
```

However I get the following error:

```
"WebApiApplication does not contain a definition for FindContainer()"
```

These are my imports:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Rest;
```

I know i'm missing an import but I haven't been able to locate it. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FindContainer() method is located in the [Global.asax.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-CreateNewConversation/Global.asax.cs) file.

Having a static method to find the container is bad practice though, as described in [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), I suggest using a dependency injection pattern instead.